# how can I get a global rss feed on Gitlab?

Tags: rss, gitlab, atom-feed

In Gitlab there is an RSS news feed button for every project.

http://git.domain.name/userName/projectName/commits/master.atom?private_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxx

Is there a way to retrieve a global RSS feed for all projects related to one user?

Or even better, if there is a way to capture all user's feeds across all projects, that would be cool.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is currently not supported.

The closest feature request there is would be "[Team-/groupwide RSS feeds](http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/3784613-team-groupwide-rss-feeds)",  to have RSS feeds for all events in a team or a group. (not enough vote for now).

---

The global "RSS" shown on [demo.gitlab.com](http://demo.gitlab.com/) is actually a html result of the `event-item`s representing the activity in response to http://demo.gitlab.com/?limit=20&offset=0:

That would be for all public projects, but I don't see it exposed as an RSS feed.

The [OP mauro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1423143/mauro) reports in the comments

> the global "RSS" shown in [demo.gitlab.com](http://demo.gitlab.com/) is also showing on my gitlab dashboard, the only thing is that mine is giving a 500 error instead.

Comment: @Mauro ok, I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility. If this is a bug, then a ticket to https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues is in order.

Comment: I've voted the group RSS feed idea: http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/3784613-team-groupwide-rss-feeds only 4 votes left to make it happen!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this even if it not about the releases, you can keep tracks on Gitlab projects with:

`https://gitlab.com/<user|group>/<project>/-/tags?format=atom`